# data table is locked on google colab sqlite

Tags: sql, google-colaboratory

I ran DROP table by mistake which blocked my data table. would anyone know how to unlock it?

[image: 1]

Comment: bonjour sarah , that can't be because of drop , unless dropping it taking too much time, which is unlikely. which database are you using? tag your db as well.

Comment: I am working with google drive ... i think ... on bachelor.db